# Infragistics license file add itself to project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-2.0, infragistics

I have a solution in VB.NET .NET 2

Use Infragistics components all over the application.

One day decided to add floating toolbar support to our Forms.

Our forms inherit one base form - BaseForm. This base form is used in multiple projects in the solution.

So, on the `BaseForm` was added a `UltraToolbarsManager`.

Since, a nightmare began: the **licenses.licx** started to create and add itself to the project on every form opened in designer....

licenses.licx contains:

> Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager,
>   Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v6.3,
>   Version=6.3.20063.53, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb

What to do? Why does this license file appear in the inherited forms?

Comment: You mean it appears as a comment in the code file? Read the license for the controls -- it probably stipulates that this must be included, and it probably won't work if you try to build without it.

Answer (score 5):

The license file only gets created when you add a control to the form.  It won't do anything if you open a form with existing Infragistics controls.

If you delete all the lines in the license.licx file after adding the control everything should work.

Our environment has a checked in license.licx file that is empty and we make source control ignore the license file so any changes on a developer machine won't make it into the build machine or anywhere elsewhere.

Comment: I have a form G:B with an Ingragistics grid. Any licence file in the project, only in the solution project output project (that generates the exe file). Now, in the base form B I add an Infragistics ToolbarManager, so, implicitly, my G form will have it. I don't know what does the designer when I open G in design mode, but it adds me the licence file to the project of G form now....

Comment: Can you just delete the license.licx file?

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of information on the licenses.licx file (and the associated wailing and gnashing of teeth that it often inspires) across the web.

Basically, this file stores the strong name of each assembly that gets loaded in the designer that participates in .NET's component licensing scheme (a simple built-in mechanism that component developers can take advantage of in determining if the developer is using a licensed or demonstration/lite version of their components).

Whenever the designer loads such an assembly, it adds the strong name of the assembly to the project that caused the load. Since you added the toolbar to your base form, opening an inherited form will cause that assembly to load, which adds the line to the file (and creates it if necessary, which is what you're seeing).

Unfortunately, there's not a lot that can be done about the issues it creates. What trouble are you having with it?

Comment: But I have other Infragistics components on the form, and none of them creates the license file in the project. I have one license file per *solution*, but not in every *project* of that solution. Many of forms uses infragistics grids, buttons, etc, but none extracts the project from sourcesafe and adds the license file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to get around this is to delete all licenses.licx files from all solutions in source control and then let Visual Studio recreate the file locally on every machine when you instance a control on the form. This file is created in your solution directory but not explicitly added to source control and should never be.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do this manually, which is relatively easy to do:

1. Copy the licx file from the old project, into the "My Project" folder of your new project.  If the "My Project" folder doesn't exist, create it.
2. Open the vbproj file in a text editor, and find the Resources.resx section, which will look like this:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\Resources.resx">
        <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
        <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

And change it to this:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\Resources.resx">
        <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
        <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\licenses.licx" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3.  Reopen the project in Visual Studio.